# DJI camera Control via API

Tags: c++, arduino, dji-sdk, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to control DJI camera using the API port on A3 cotnroller. The drone i have is custom built. The reason i want to integrate DJI camera is because they have been so far the best. So any suggestion would be welcome.

Please let me know if the whether the direct control of the camera is possible or not. If yes then how can it be done?

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. "How can I do X" without showing any trial & error on your part is not a good question

Answer (score 0):

A3 can allow you to use servo and digital IO. If you camera has direct PWM based control method, then you can direct connect in and control it by API . you can follow the sample here on how to do it  https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-ROS/blob/3.8/dji_sdk_demo/src/demo_mfio.cpp

And usually, we connect A3 to a manifold 2. Manifold 2 has Serial/digital control output that can allow you to connect to the camera such as IDS and Pointgrey camera. Follow the camera manufactures guide to implement the camera control function such as external trigger/sync, apecture, focus etc. If it is just a normal webcam, it is even easier. Connect the camera in and adjust the setting by this http://www.techytalk.info/webcam-settings-control-ubuntu-linux/